# Interactive Form depending on Select List not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I am trying to make this clip submission form interactive in the following way:

I want the second Select list choices to change according to which city is selected in the first select list.

Here is my script function code:

```
<script>
function spotListChange(s1, s2) {
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if(s1.value == ""){
        var optionArray = ["|"];
    }
    <?php
    while ($cityList = $cityListDB->fetch()) {
        $city = $cityList['city'];
        $spotList = $db->query("SELECT * FROM spots WHERE city='$city' ORDER BY name");
        ?>
        else if(s1.value == "<?php echo $city; ?>"){
            var optionArray = ["|"
                                <?php
                                while ($spot = $spotList->fetch()) {
                                    echo ", \"" . $spot['city'] . "|" . $spot['city'] . "\"";
                                }
                                ?>
                                ];
        }

    <?php
    }
    ?>

    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the part of the form with the two select lists. (I'll get rid of most city options available just to make the code shorter)

```
    <select id="city" name="city" style="margin-left: 135px;" onChange="spotListChange('city', 'spotSelectList')" required>
        <option value="" selected="selected">Ville...</option>
        <option value="Albanel">Albanel</option>
        <option value="Alma">Alma</option>
        <option value="La Doré">La Doré</option>
        <option value="Saint-Félicien">Saint-Félicien</option>
        <option value="Mashteuiatsh">Mashteuiatsh</option>  
    </select><br />
    <select id="spotSelectList" name="spot" style="margin-left: 135px;">
    </select>
```

If I change the PHP inside the else if by fix/text values, it works fine, so the issue must be there, but I don't get where the issue is.

Comment: I'm going to be honest and say I have no idea what is going on with that code. Can you expand a bit on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Steven Well I only included the part of the form which I thought was relevant; the whole form is really just a regular form to submit a skateboarding clip to the server to get reviewed. The code that is here is to specify the city in which the clip has been recorded, and the second select list should be showing the Skateparks and Spots that are in this specific city and stocked on the server (or atleast that's what I'm trying to get it to do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and use jquery for it, it makes your code more simple and is a plenty of tutorial out there. 
I recomend you make a json response from php to an ajax call from jquery (javascript).

Can you see this as reference:http://simpleweb.github.io/jquery-dependent-selects/
also this:http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't have much time to actually learn all of this new stuff right now, although I would love to if I have enough time soon. But would there be any other way to solve my issue, as it looks like I'm pretty much all good except one tiny part of code? :/ If not I guess I'll have to wait a bit and learn all of that before I can fix this...

Comment: it's not so hard to learn in one day you can learn it, the links I posted explain it clearly, give my answer a chance.

Comment: By the way the code you use is useless, ugly, not portable, and hard to understand, I tryed to mimic your code (having no your database) using arrays and works but is really awfull code, I post another answer